# Looks like I get multiple browser calls to API

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, gunicorn

I have an application where the frontend is implemented in HTML/JavaScript and backend in Python/Nignx/Gunicorn/Flask. My issue is for a particular part of this application. When an external user login, the user is presented with an HTML page that contains a number files that can be download one by one. When the user click the download button for a file the following happens in the same JavaScript function:

1. Call Flask API to request download to be added to a history table
2. Call Flask API to request the file; Flask submits the file using 'send_file'

   The download is split into two different API calls, since the #2 call can happen multiple times if a browser request a partial download using the Range HTTP header.

In my Flask log I see a very odd behavior. Quite often it looks like the #1 call happens multiple times, within very few seconds, but only once for the #2. So I does not seem like this is the user clicking multiple time, also I would expect add history API call the same number times as the download API call. Since it is in the same function, and the function is called from a button onclick event, I am baffled how that can happen. I just dont see what user/browser/JavaScript scenarios that would lead to below behavior, which obviously makes it very difficult to debug as I dont know how to recreate the problem.

(Please ignore the GET method for the history call, it has been changed to PUT)

```
2022-11-06T16:04:52+00:00 vm api[2314991]: [2022-11-06 16:04:52 +0000] [2314991] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:53+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:04:53 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:53+00:00 vm api[2314991]: [2022-11-06 16:04:53 +0000] [2314991] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:54+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:04:54 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:55+00:00 vm api[2314991]: [2022-11-06 16:04:55 +0000] [2314991] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:55+00:00 vm api[2314991]: [2022-11-06 16:04:55 +0000] [2314991] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:56+00:00 vm api[2830469]: [2022-11-06 16:04:56 +0000] [2830469] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:57+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:04:57 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:04:57+00:00 vm api[2830469]: [2022-11-06 16:04:57 +0000] [2830469] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:01+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:05:01 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:02+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:05:02 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:02+00:00 vm api[2314991]: [2022-11-06 16:05:02 +0000] [2314991] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:03+00:00 vm api[2830469]: [2022-11-06 16:05:03 +0000] [2830469] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:03+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:05:03 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:05:15+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:05:15 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/download/49


2022-11-06T16:13:30+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:13:30 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:13:30+00:00 vm api[2830469]: [2022-11-06 16:13:30 +0000] [2830469] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:13:31+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:13:31 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:13:53+00:00 vm api[2954187]: [2022-11-06 16:13:53 +0000] [2954187] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:13:53+00:00 vm api[2939769]: [2022-11-06 16:13:53 +0000] [2939769] [DEBUG] GET /token/history/49
2022-11-06T16:13:53+00:00 vm api[2830469]: [2022-11-06 16:13:53 +0000] [2830469] [DEBUG] GET /token/download/49
```

All the files are listed in an HTML table with a download button, that I build dynamically

```
            let download = "<span>";
            download += "<button onclick=\"consumer_download_file(";
            download += file_id;
            download += ")\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn--toggle-status\">";
            download += '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i>';
            download += " </button></span>";
            cell.innerHTML = download;
```

It looks like this the file HTML page:

```
<button onclick="consumer_download_file(49)" type="button" class="btn--toggle-status"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i> </button>
```

Download function looks like this

```
window.consumer_download_file = function(file_id) {
    // Add to download history
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    let urlhist = domain_url;
    urlhist += "/token/history";
    urlhist += "/" + file_id;
    fetch(urlhist, requestOptions)
    .then(r =>  r.json().then(data => ({status: r.status, body: data})))
    .then(result => {
        console.log("body = ", result.body);
        console.log("status = ", result.status);
    });


    // Download file
    let url = domain_url;
    url += "/token/download";
    url += "/" + file_id;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have the console log of the browser when it happens? maybe javascript is crashing before the 2nd API call to /token/download. Another idea: maybe the download process is so long that the user may wonder what's happening and click multiple times. Disabling the button when consumer_download_file starts would be a good idea

Comment: Users are "anonymous", so I dont have access to the console, would have been nice. Yes I have been wondering about the first call crashing, but I cannot think of a scenario I can recreate and test. Regarding disabling the button and slow download, I would just think that even if you click it multiple times, I would have as many history as downloads API call queued on top of each other, but maybe not. I believe I have a way to simulate low bandwidth and high latency, I will look into that and I see if can trigger the issue.